# Bridge edge loop acting weird between 2 clean edge loops

Tags: mesh, 3d-view

How edges looks like before bridge edge loop: [image: Before]

How mesh looks like after bridge edge loop: [image: After]

Why is it acting so weird, 8 edges in the first loop, 8 edges in the second loop, that seems simple to connect. Am I doing something wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the vanilla "*Bridge Edge loop*" is not quite efficient.

I tried the "*Bridge*" tool from "Loop Tools" addon, it works like a charm:

[image: demo gif]

This addon is shipped in Blender. Just enable it in the user preferences and you will find the *Loop Tools* submenu in the *Specials menu* (<kbd>W</kbd> by default).

Comment: It's kind of interesting to know _why_ Bridge Edge Loops isn't working.. it doesn't like the clockwise/anticlockwise order of vertices in the inner loop. If you fill the inner loop and send its normal in the same direction as the other faces, B.E.L  works. Perhaps the tool needs a 'reverse' option like the Loop Tools version.